# Error when updating Quarkus to 3.1.3: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core.StreamReadConstraints

Tags: quarkus, smallrye, jackson-dataformat-yaml

I'm trying to update from Quarkus 2.14 to 3.1.3, but I'm getting this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:3.1.3.Final:build (default) on project app: Failed to build quarkus application: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
[ERROR]         [error]: Build step io.quarkus.smallrye.openapi.deployment.SmallRyeOpenApiProcessor#build threw an exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core.StreamReadConstraints com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLParser.streamReadConstraints()'
[ERROR]         at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLParser._parseNumericValue(YAMLParser.java:1109)
[ERROR]         at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserBase.getNumberType(ParserBase.java:678)
[ERROR]         at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.BaseNodeDeserializer._fromFloat(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:751)
[ERROR]         at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.BaseNodeDeserializer._deserializeContainerNoRecursion(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:576)
[ERROR]         at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JsonNodeDeserializer.deserialize(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:98)
[ERROR]         at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JsonNodeDeserializer.deserialize(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:23)
[ERROR]         at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323)
[ERROR]         at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readTreeAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4772)
[ERROR]         at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:3104)
[ERROR]         at io.smallrye.openapi.runtime.io.OpenApiParser.parse(OpenApiParser.java:86)
[ERROR]         at io.smallrye.openapi.runtime.OpenApiProcessor.modelFromStaticFile(OpenApiProcessor.java:126)
[ERROR]         at io.smallrye.openapi.runtime.OpenApiProcessor.modelFromStaticFile(OpenApiProcessor.java:97)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.smallrye.openapi.deployment.SmallRyeOpenApiProcessor.generateStaticModel(SmallRyeOpenApiProcessor.java:838)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.smallrye.openapi.deployment.SmallRyeOpenApiProcessor.build(SmallRyeOpenApiProcessor.java:728)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:909)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:282)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

I have already reviewed the dependency tree. All dependencies are using jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.15.2 and jackson-core:jar:2.15.2.

Comment: Hello @Hiago William Petris , what version of the quarkus-maven-plugin are you using?

Comment: @MichaelEdgar 3.1.3.Final

Comment: is there any additional configuration or dependencies specified for the plugin? Based on the stack trace, it seems as though Jackson < 2.15 is being pulled in by the plugin during the build.

Comment: @MichaelEdgar this is the plugin config: https://pastebin.com/5ZzAG5Lx

This is the dependency:tree: https://pastebin.com/Kvu84tVQ

There is no reference to Jackson < 2.15